# Using a List(Of String) as a Class Property

Tags: vb.net, list, class, properties

I am having problems with using a List in a Class Property.
This is my Class:

```
Public Class SourceData
    Private _datafiles As New List(Of String)
    Public Property datafiles() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _datafiles
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            _datafiles = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

So far, so good. Now I want to use it in my program:

```
Public filename_data As New List(Of SourceData)

Private Sub loadData()
    Dim currentSourceData As New SourceData

    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("A")
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("B")
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("C")
    MsgBox(currentSourceData.datafiles.Count) 'Returns 3

    filename_data.Add(currentSourceData)
    MsgBox(filename_data(0).datafiles.Count) 'Returns 0
end sub
```

The first message box will return the correct number of datafile-entries: 3
However, the second message box will return 0. Somehow, the List of datafiles got lost on the way? I could not find a solution to my problem, no matter what I tried.

Comment: Something isn't right here -- you're leaving something out because you can't have `Public filename_data As New List(Of SourceData)` in a method.  Can you show *all* of your code?

Comment: Also, I've run your code and it says "3" both times.

Comment: Same here - are you sure that your 'MsgBox(filename_data(0).datafiles.Count)' statement in your actual code occurs *after* you've added the data 'A', 'B', & 'C'?

Comment: What does filename_data.Count return? Are you sure that index 0 is the item you just added? Maybe you should do MessageBox.Show(filename_data(filename_data.Count-1).datafiles.Count)

Comment: Nothing is wrong here.  Something else is going on.

Comment: This is really strange. I am currently looking into it, but didn't find the error. I can't post all code because it is too long. However, I think it has something to do with the class definition and New constructor. My filename_data somehow  always returns the same values for each item. I will add a more thorough code for you to look at above!

Comment: @roryap I edited the example above and tested the code in a separate program - the problem persists. I hope the example is now better to understand.

Comment: please do not *change* the question radically once an answer has been posted as it makes the answers look incorrect

Comment: I am sorry, @Plutonix, my questioning was confused and I apologize for the change. All answers were very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding 'currentSourceData' to the list three times:

```
filename_data.Add(currentSourceData)
```

'currentSourceData' is always the same instance - you're just adding this to the list 3 times, so of course you'll get the same count for each of the duplicate instances.  And that count will be 3 since your 'for each' loop occurs after the string list was cleared and then 3 strings added.

Another way to look at this is that your List(Of SourceData) has 3 entries by the end of 'loadData' - and each entry points to the same object. There is no copying going on here, which is what I think you expected.

If you want the objects to be independent after adding, then you need to add clones of 'currentSourceData' to the list.

Comment: Thank you, Dave! This seems correct. However, I am trying to create clones of currentSourceData to add to the list for half an hour now. Could you describe how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that cloning is really what you want - if it is then your SourceData class will need a method within it to create a clone of itself.  The clone method will need to copy the object state (i.e., the fields) to a new instance and return that new instance.

Comment: Hm, I think I got something totally wrong here. My head hurts right now, so I better take a break but here's a short description of what I want to do: I am looping through folders, i.e.:
`For Each dri In diArr       If File.Exists(...) Then  ... currentSourceData.datafiles.add(FilePath) End If ... filename_data.Add(currentSourceData) ... Next dri` There are other properties of the class I am adding within the for each.. next statement. I just want to have a List of Folder-Names with List of Files (and other infos) for each foldername.

Comment: Finally I got it! I had to declare currentSourceData = New SourceData each time after adding it to the list of SourceData!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my final code, thanks to your hints I found my problem:

```
    Public filename_data As New List(Of SourceData)

Private Sub loadData()
    Dim currentSourceData As New SourceData
    'first Item:
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("A")
    MsgBox(currentSourceData.datafiles.Count) 'Returns 1
    filename_data.Add(currentSourceData)
    currentSourceData = New SourceData
    'second Item:
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("A")
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("B")
    MsgBox(currentSourceData.datafiles.Count) 'Returns 2
    filename_data.Add(currentSourceData)
    currentSourceData = New SourceData
    'third Item:
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("A")
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("B")
    currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("C")
    MsgBox(currentSourceData.datafiles.Count) 'Returns 3
    filename_data.Add(currentSourceData)


    For Each x As SourceData In filename_data
        MessageBox.Show(x.datafiles.Count) 'Will Return 1.. 2.. 3
    Next
end sub
```